# Trouble grasping the usage of react or CSS

Tags: css, reactjs

For example, you can create a scrolling function in CSS using

```
.overflow{
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
overflow-x: scroll;
background: green;
}
```

Why would someone use a component such as react-scrollbar

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scrollbar

I presume that you have more options styling it when using JSX?

Answer (score 1):

Browser-generated UI components (such as scrollbars, resize-handles and some UI components in HTML forms) can appear "a bit clunky" and are known for being difficult to style consistently across all browsers, platforms and devices.

This has always been the case historically and the situation persists at present.

The intention behind using javascript (or a JS library or framework) to reproduce native browser-generated UI is to enable the production of a UI component look and feel which:

- is highly customised to the website / web-app; and
- remains consistent across all platforms.